# MultiPHP Manager Reports Site Is Using A Version Of PHP That It Isn't

Tags: php, cpanel, whm, easyapache-4

There are two sites running on a server with WHM V60.0. Both domains were assigned to PHP7 using the MultiPHP Manager, the default PHP version for the server is 5.6.

I tested both sites pre-live, and they were absolutely running PHP7. Verified via PHP info, and the fact that I had to remove a couple of eregi's that I missed.  Tested sites for three weeks, all was good and switched DNS to new server.

Now, a week later, both sites are using PHP 5.6, verified via PHP info. But, the MultiPHP Manager still says their PHP Version is 7.  The only reason I noticed the switch was by looking at the running processes and seeing all the processes were pulled from /ea-php56/.  They switched "by themselves" apparently.

Has anyone experience this issue with WHM 60? Or, does anyone have a suggestion as to where to begin to trouble-shoot?